# Does changing the value of an object in a subarray change the value of the object in the "main" array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I am working with an array of object in p5.js. If some condition related to a value of the object is met, I create another array to hold those 'valid' objects.

I want to change the value of the object for both the 'valid objects' array and the 'main' array. If I change it from the 'valid obj' array, does it change it from the 'main' array too?

```
var objects[]; 
var validObjects[];

function setup() {
    createObj();
    myFunc2();
}

function object( name, condition ) {
    // Define a class called 'object'.
    this.name = name;
    this.condition = condition;
}

function createObj() {
    objects[0] = new object( 'obj0', true );
    objects[1] = new object( 'obj1', true );
    objects[2] = new object( 'obj2', false );
    objects[3] = new object( 'obj3', false );
}

function myFunc() {
    // Pick out the valid objects and put them into another array.
    for( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++ ) {
        if( objects[i].condition == true )
            validObjects.push( objects[i] );
}

function myFunc2() {
    // Change a field of the objects from the new array.
    for( var i = 0; i < validObjects.length; i++ )
        objects[i].condition = !objects[i].condition;
}
```

Does myFunc2() change the condition field of the objects forever? Or should I approach this differently?

EDITS: Fixed syntax.

Comment: `object[i].condition` should probably be `objects[i].condition`? (Note the missing `s`) That said, have you tried running the code? The answer to the question should be pretty obvious if you do, and then look at the result.

Comment: You could test this and answer the question by yourself.

Comment: `If I change it from the 'valid obj' array, does it change it from the 'main' array too?` - Test it and let us know.

Comment: @Cerbrus that is right. I have edited the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in javascript all objects are assigned by reference and not value.  When you want to make a copy of an object you need to clone it.

```
 var clone = Object.assign({}, cloneTarget);
```

Also your syntax on:

```
objects[0] = new object( obj0, true );
```

Seems to be off you should be changing these names to `literals` and not `identifiers` correct?

```
objects[0] = new object( 'obj0', true );
```

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as `new object(<params>)`

Comment: read the code example from OP. He uses a function indentifier that he defined as a constructor.  Making the syntax for `new object(<params>)` valid.

Comment: That is correct, the `name` of the objects should have been strings.